# Is gcc 4.9.x stable version?

Tags: gcc, gcc4.9

*Hu, I was surprised at read-only mode...*

Anyway, I know many program uses [even-odd version numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Odd-numbered_versions_for_development_releases), like linux kernel 2.x.

> [major version].[major revision].[minor revision]
>
> If major revision is odd, it's unstable version.

But in [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/gcc), it says that gcc 4.9.0 is stable version.

Does *NOT* gcc uses that version numbering? But I've heard that gcc 4.7 has many bugs, so I can't make sure..

Comment: as you can see for yourself https://gcc.gnu.org/ , GCC 4.9.0 is a milestone and official release from the GCC team. Please don't refer to Wikipedia for serious stuff, it's a webpage that basically anyone can edit, pick your sources with the same care you expect from the makers of the software that you use.

Comment: Linus Torvalds seems to have complained heavily on 4.9.0 at least: http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/1407.3/00650.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every released version of GCC is as stable as it can be.

C++ compilers are in a perpetual race to keep up with the progress of the ISO C++ standard. Features are continually being introduced. Currently C++11 is mostly complete and most work is going toward `-std=c++1y` mode. GCC 4.7 happened to be at the peak of C++11 feature introduction, which might explain its reputation for bugs.

To be sure, **there is no advantage to running an older release version of the compiler,** at least for code that is reliably compliant (portable, not depending on compiler bugs) in the first place. This holds true for any of the modern C++ compilers.

A more relevant question may be whether you want to run a prerelease version or not. Often, the "bleeding edge" contains more bugfixes than bugs.

Comment: I always want to run latest version of compiler so much that I threw my cross-built gcc 4.8.2 away as soon as 4.8.3 released and spent much time cross-building it.. After going back home, I'll do the same for 4.9.0 >o<

Answer (score 4):

It makes complete sense to stick with the "latest and greatest" release when it comes to modern compilers. Although it is a fact (just not a readily acceptable one) - Compilers, like other software, are prone to bugs.

The best you can do before committing with a particular release, is take a look at the open issues / bugs reported in that release and see how they affect you. Like one of the recent [bug posting 61904 for GCC 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61904) which is miscompiling the linux kernel !